# Add published confirms for convertSendAndReceive

Tags: java, spring-amqp

I'm using this code to send and receive Java Object.

```
TransactionsBean reply = (TransactionsBean) processingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(EXCHANGE_PROCESSING,
                ROUTING_KEY_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION, obj);
```

I'm thinking is there a need for implementing publisher confirms? Is it better to extend the code in order to ensure reliable delivery or I can just ass try catch block and with replyTimeout to resend again the object? What  would be the better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They really represent two different things.

A publisher confirm simply means the message was successfully routed to the queue by the destination.

Not receiving a reply can be for many reasons

- the message wasn't delivered to a queue
- the server is not running
- the server has had some failure

Resending for the latter two cases might not make sense.

So it all depends on your use case.